# Calling function from a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call a function and the function name is stored into a variable, but it is giving error. I am trying to call a function `uploadDocumentCallback` but its name is stored into a variable

```
$scope.uploadDocumentCallback(data,status,headers,config);  //its working fine if i'm passing callback function name directly.
$scope.callback = "uploadDocumentCallback"; //this is my variable where I store function name

var callbackFunction = $scope.callback;

$scope.callbackFunction(data,status,headers,config); //not working
callbackFunction(data,status,headers,config); //not working

$scope.callback(data,status,headers,config); //not working
```

Please suggest me that how can I achieve this?

Comment: `$scope.callback` is a string so it is hardly surprising that it isn't calling the function. You never try to perform any lookup to obtain the function object.

Answer (score 0):

I managed it to work

```
$scope[$scope.callback](data,status,headers,config);
```